# access same directory from multiple domains

Tags: apache, hosting, plesk

Hi I have several domains that would like to access the same image repository.  Is there an easy way of doing this?  I am running plesk on linux.

I have found this page https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory. with this syntax to be put in the additional directives for http and https sections in the server settings.

will this

```html
<Directory "/usr/local/httpd/htdocs">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

allow me to read and write to those directories?

Answer (score 0):

`FollowSymLinks` option will allow exactly it - Apache will be able to process data which is not physically located inside domain directory, but is referred to by a symlink located inside domain directory.
There are two major points that you should be aware of:

1. You should have sufficient permission for system users of the domain which will be accessing shared files on the directory which contain these files. Basically, `chmod 666` will do the job, but it is up to you how exactly set up rights to maintain desirable security level.

2. If websites are using PHP code, you should ensure that shared directory is included in `open_basedir` value.

This link can be useful - [How to change open_basedir parameter for all domains?](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213919825)